# Configure Nginx upload file size per file

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure the upload size per file with nginx?

I have currently configured client_max_body_size 20m;. If I now upload a file with 20479 kB, it works.
If it is a file with 20480 kB, the upload fails with the status code 413.
Two files with 20479 kB also fail.

I would like to be able to upload several files, each with a maximum size of 20 mb.